# Whcms domain whois API doesn't work

Tags: php, content-management-system, dns, whois

So here is my code:

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.site.com/whcms/includes/api.php"; # This is not the original url, just an exapmle
$username = "user"; # Admin username goes here
$password = "pass"; # Admin password goes here

$postfields["username"] = $username;
$postfields["password"] = md5($password);
$postfields["action"] = "domainwhois"; #action performed by the API:Functions
$postfields["domain"] = "whmcs.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo(var_dump($data));
?>
```

I get this: `string(44) "result=error;message=Invalid IP 89.24.47.30;"`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Found!

Go into the admin panel, General Settings -> Security and add the ip address